# Passing Pandas dataframe to function in python

Tags: python, pandas

I need to do a lot of data wrangling on multiple data frame. Instead of writing plenty of lines to do the same stuff on them. I would like to you either pass them to a function or use decorator or any other efficient alternative.
Given that pandas dataframe is global, I am looking for comment on efficient way to this kind of tasks..

My Problem looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

def data_extraction():
#Here will fetch data from mongodb"
     df1 = pd.DataFrame(X1)
     .
     .
     df10= pd.DataFrame(X2)
##These 10 data frames have data corresponding to students in 10 different school
```

#### Do some Data Wrangling to make data frame useable

```
    def cleanup(df):    
        df.describe()
####Here I basically want to add some functionality to vary sampling fraction based on population
        df_pruned=df.sample(frac=0.2))
    return df_pruned

# Apply some machine learning
def ML(df):
#import pymrmr
     pymrmr.mRMR(df, 'MIQ',6)
     .

if __name__ == "__main__":
     df1.......df10 = data_extraction()
     df_pruned_1 =cleanup(df1)
```

Comment: Ten different DataFrames?! Is there no better alternative?

Comment: Not very clear about your motive, If you are looking for a discussion here, and gathering more info(), pls refer https://towardsdatascience.com/data-wrangling-with-pandas-5b0be151df4e. basic methods coded in python

Comment: @AlexanderCécile yes, unfortunately no better alternative